# react modal still showing the main component where it came from

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Hello im new in learning react i am facing an issue where when i show my popup modal component i can still see and click on my main ui can you help me with this

[image]

```
     import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import styled from 'styled-components'
    import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
    import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
    import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
    import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
    import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
    import { postinfo } from '../services/node';
    import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
    import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
    import Msgbox from './msgbox';
    const Container = styled.div`
         background: white;
         
         
         display: flex;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
         flex-direction: column;
         
         margin-top: 5rem;
         transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
         
        
         h4{
            font-size:22px;
            font-weight: 500;
            color: grey;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h1{
            font-size:30px;
            font-weight: 1500;
            color: #007f7b;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            text-align: center;
        }
      
        p{
            font-size:25px;
            font-weight: 100;
            color: black;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        label{
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 400;
            color: grey;
            margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
            text-align: center;
        }
       
    `;
    const InputSection= styled.div`
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 350px;
        max-width: 450px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 1rem;
    
        label{
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: 400;
            color: grey;
           
        }
        input{
            border: 3px solid #eee;
            border-radius: 1rem;
            background-color: transparent;
            outline: none;
            padding: 12px 3px 12px 15px;
            font-size: 16px;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
            z-index: 500;
            &:hover,
            &:focus{
                box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(8,11,14,0.06), 
                0 16px 16px -1px rgba(8,11,14,0.1);
            }
    
        }
        
    `;
    const SubmitButton= styled.button`
        background-color: #007f7b;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        width: 150px;
        height: 36px;
        font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        letter-spacing: 0.03rem;
        line-height: 36px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(8,11,14,0.06), 
                0 6px 6px -1px rgba(8,11,14,0.1);
               
        &:hover{
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(8,11,14,0.06), 
            0 16px 16px -1px rgba(8,11,14,0.1);
        }
        margin-top: 2rem;
    `;
    const Error = styled.h1`
        color:red;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    `;
    const modal= styled.div`
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    `
const UserUi =function(){
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
const openModal = () => {
        setShowModal(prev => !prev);
      };
  return (
                <div>
                    <Container>
                        
                        <h4>Your Contact Information</h4>
                        <InputSection type="email" name='email' onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}>
                        <Error>{email.error}</Error>
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input 
                        type="text">
                        </input>
                        </InputSection>
                        <InputSection type="text" name='name' onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}> 
                        <Error>{name.error}</Error>
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input 
                        type="text">
                        </input>
                        </InputSection>
                        <InputSection type="text" name='phone' onChange={e => setPhone(e.target.value)}>
                        <Error>{phone.error}</Error>
                        <label>Phone</label>
                        <input 
                        type="text">
                        </input>
                        </InputSection>
                        <InputSection type="text" name='refe' onChange={e => setReference(e.target.value)}>
                        <label>Referring Advisor</label>
                        <input 
                        type="text">
                        </input>
                        </InputSection>
                        
                        <SubmitButton type='submit' onClick={openModal}>Save</SubmitButton>
                        <Msgbox showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} />
                    </Container>
                   
                   
                    </div>
                )
       
       
    }


export default UserUi
```

and here is the modal component

```
import React, { useState as UseState, useEffect as UseEffect ,useRef as UseRef, useCallback as UseCallback} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import { postinfo } from '../services/node';
import { useHistory as Userhistory } from "react-router-dom";
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import { MdClose } from 'react-icons/md';
import { useSpring as UseSpring, animated as Animated} from 'react-spring';
const Background = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const ModalWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 10px;
`;

const ModalImg = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  background: #000;
`;

const ModalContent = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #141414;
  p {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
  button {
    padding: 10px 24px;
    background: #141414;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
  }
`;

const CloseModalButton = styled(MdClose)`
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 10;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
     h4{
        font-size:45px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #007f7b;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        
        text-align: center;
    }
    h3{
        font-size:20px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: black;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        
        text-align: center;
    }
    p{
        font-size:25px;
        font-weight: 100;
        color: black;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    label{
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: grey;
        margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
`;

const SubmitButton= styled.button`
    background-color: #007f7b;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    width: 150px;
    height: 36px;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.03rem;
    line-height: 36px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(8,11,14,0.06), 
            0 6px 6px -1px rgba(8,11,14,0.1);
           
    &:hover{
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 rgba(8,11,14,0.06), 
        0 16px 16px -1px rgba(8,11,14,0.1);
    }
    margin-top: 2rem;
`;
const Error = styled.h1`
    color:red;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
`;


export const msgbox = ({ showModal, setShowModal }) => {
    const [Fist, setFirst] = UseState('');
    const [second, setSecond] = UseState('');
    const [third, setThird] = UseState('');
    const modalRef = UseRef();

    const animation = UseSpring({
      config: {
        duration: 250
      },
      opacity: showModal ? 1 : 0,
      transform: showModal ? `translateY(0%)` : `translateY(-100%)`
    });
  
    const closeModal = e => {
      if (modalRef.current === e.target) {
        setShowModal(false);
      }
    };
  
    const keyPress = UseCallback(
      e => {
        if (e.key === 'Escape' && showModal) {
          setShowModal(false);
          console.log('I pressed');
        }
      },
      [setShowModal, showModal]
    );
  
    UseEffect(
      () => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
        return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', keyPress);
      },
      [keyPress]
    );
    History = Userhistory();
    
  
    
        return (
          <>
      {showModal ? (
        <Background onClick={closeModal} ref={modalRef}>
          <Animated.div style={animation}>
            <ModalWrapper showModal={showModal}>
              <ModalImg src={require('../assets/modal.jpg')} alt='camera' />
              <ModalContent>
                <h1>Are you ready?</h1>
                <p>Get exclusive access to our next launch.</p>
                <button>Join Now</button>
              </ModalContent>
              <CloseModalButton
                aria-label='Close modal'
                onClick={() => setShowModal(prev => !prev)}
              />
            </ModalWrapper>
          </Animated.div>
        </Background>
      ) : null}
    </>
        
        )
    }


export default msgbox
```

advance thanks to you guys hope you can help me i tried alot of ways how i can show the modal but i still have no answer. i am just trying to show the modal in front of my user component am i doing anything wrong on my styled-component or i put the modal component on the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input tags' z-index property is causing the inputs to appear on top of the modal.  Setting it to zero should fix that.

References:

w3schools.com. CSS z-index Property. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp. (accessed November 22, 2020)